# Info about frigates crossing the Atlantic in 1650

Tags: 17th-century, ships

I'm writing a book and need help with trading frigates crossing the Atlantic in 1650 to the West Indies and American colonies. How many men would be on a ship and were there stairs or ladders leading to the decks below?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Did you perform some research, that we could compare or extend?

Comment: Both of those questions would depend completely on the individual ship and what kind of trade it was conducting.

Comment: @TylerDurden Frigates were warships and were not intended for trade purposes other than privateering and securing own trade routes.

Comment: @Voitcus Tell the OP, he wrote "trading frigates" in his question.

Comment: @Voitcus In the 1650's the word 'frigate' was used to describe any ship of fine lines that was built for speed. Its use to denote a class of cruising warship came later.

Comment: Note that in Naval parlance, there is no difference between "ladders" and "stairs".  If there are no stairs, I'm not sure how you get abovedeck (you could presumably jump down).

Comment: Most sailing ships (and most ships today, in fact) have what are termed Ships Ladders which are less than stairs but more than true ladders. They are installed at a 68 degree angle and are VERY steep. A sailor can slide down easily, once learned and going up is also actually easier at the steep 68 than if it were a true ladder. If you Google "Ship Ladder" you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: Frigates are warships. They are not trading vessels. One should not refer to a trading vessel, even if it used to be a military vessel as a frigate. Very different rigging you see.

Comment: @Stuart Allen As I've already noted above, the assertion that frigates are purely warships isn't true in the time period covered in the question. Faulkner's 'Universal Dictionary of the Marine' (1784) includes the following as part of its definition of 'Frigate' - "Formerly the name of Frigate was only known in the Mediterranean, and applied to a kind of long vessel, navigated in that sea with sails and oars. The English were the first who appeared on the [Atlantic] ocean with those ships and equiped them for war as well as commerce."

Comment: @SteveBird I stand corrected. Thank you for taking the time to point out my error, great citation!

Comment: Trading frigates? What is this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Mayflower was a small-ish merchant ship (Dutch Fluyt)](http://www.wvhcgs.com/vessel.htm) of the early 17th Century ~100 tons burden. [With a crew of ~25-30 men and boys](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~mosmd/17cnav.htm).

Also all the models/diagrams seem to show stairs from the half deck to the upper deck and to the deck below that above the hold (and maybe down to the orlop deck or hold )